# On a multi-monitor system, with displays of varying heights, the mouse goes off screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

Ubuntu 22.04, up to date. Had to reboot into Windows briefly today, and when I came back this problem presented itself.

Display settings:
[image: Display settings]

Three displays, one of which is portrait which is both higher and lower than the other two.

If I drag a window to the top of the screen, it just keeps going instead of maximizing.

[image: Window extends above screen]

Oh interesting. This was in the corner of displays 3 and 2. I can take a screenshot of the off-screen areas.

The void above the primary display. The off-screen areas screenshot as transparent:
[image: The void above the primary display]

It *seems* like [this old bug from 11 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29478/monitor-height-differences-the-mouse-going-off-screen) which has long been fixed. And yet, it's currently happening to me.

I have tried:

- Restarting
- Changing graphics driver (both newer and older)
- Deleting ~/.config/monitors.xml
- dconf reset /com/ubuntu/user-interface/scale-factor
- Disconnecting/reconnecting external displays

Comment: It's not just above, it's also below. When I try to click on programs in the taskbar, it's easy to miss it and go under it. Very frustrating!